# where does Linux store the information the trash can uses?

Tags: trash

I've found many post on how to get a trash can on the system. What I am looking for is the, "how does Linux know where to put that trash back to"? where is the file that holds this information on where each file came from so it knows where to put it back to kept, and how do I get at it?

Comment: What implementation of this trash bin are you talking about?

Comment: ah ha it seems it maybe more complected then I thought. Now I got a figure that out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trash stuff is inside `~/.local/share/Trash`:

```
xb@dnxb:~/.local/share/Trash$ t
.
├── expunged/
├── files/
│   ├── love/
│   │   ├── lala
│   │   └── lolo
│   └── testing
└── info/
    ├── love.trashinfo
    └── testing.trashinfo

4 directories, 5 files
xb@dnxb:~/.local/share/Trash$ recurcat c *

 Filepath:  files/love/lala

abc

 Filepath:  files/love/lolo

555

 Filepath:  files/testing



 Filepath:  info/love.trashinfo

[Trash Info]
Path=/home/xiaobai/Documents/love
DeletionDate=2016-11-15T23:25:15

 Filepath:  info/testing.trashinfo

[Trash Info]
Path=/home/xiaobai/Music/testing
DeletionDate=2016-11-15T23:29:17
xb@dnxb:~/.local/share/Trash$
```

As you can see, the `info` directory stored the `Path=<original_path>` info, of course no problem to restore it later.

Note that you should do `killall -9 gvfsd-trash gvfsd-metadata` to force it reread the path without reboot, in case you manually edit the path to something else. p/s: This trick apply to GNOME.